# Correcting slope of river bed on DEM using QGIS or ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, dem, slope, altitude

I have a DEM that has incorrect value of altitude/slope in the river bed area. This is a result of the interpolation of elevation value that are close to the river and creates lots of errors.

[image]

In fact (as you can see in the image above) in some points the bed river go up.

I would like to correct the value of the DTM in the river bed and set a plausible values.

Comment: What is the source of your DEM data? It appears that you're looking for accurate bathymetry data, but it's unclear if your DEM is merely surface elevation data.

Comment: Check out the SAGA tool called "burn stream network into DEM"

Comment: Hi, and thanks for replying! The source of the DEM is a regional administration geo-database and yes, represent the elevation of the terrain. I already tried the 'burn stream network into DEM' tool, but I just obtained the same DEM input lowered by a set value. So the 'strange' terrain shape remain. I would like to smooth it and set a slope that can be 'real'.

Comment: That DTM is the product of erroneous interpolation. They appear to have relieved only some significant points of the riverbed, and interpolated along with the topography of the land without any break lines. You don't have access to the original points to interpolate them again?

Comment: If you are only interested in the river bed, you should extract only the (three or four) lowest points of that DEM, interpolate them with each other, cut the river DEM with its polygon, and replace the original dem with the new values. The terrain, if you can't get the original points, seems to me unrecoverable.

Comment: Hi @GabrielDeLuca, thanks for spend your time to answer! Unfortunately I don't have the original points, but as you said  I can run an interpolation with the lowest points of the DEM on the river bed and then clip the result with the river polygon!

Comment: @GiulioDonatiSarti You are welcome. Please, when you finish doing it, I would appreciate if you can write the answer detailing how you did it (you can even accept your own answer as valid) so it adds to the community knowledge.